# how to make comments attached to respective posts

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, rdbms

I'm trying to create a commenting system to posts in an example site.And I can't seem to print the exact comments to its original post.I created two tables `updates` and `comment_update` and kept `os_id` as the common table row, where it is referring to update_id of updates table. everything seems OK except for the loops which is screwing up the output. Any advice on how to rectify it as I tried with while & other loops everything gives the same problem. 

Here is my code for that logic:

```
<?php
    $status_replies="";
    $statusui_edit="";
    $status2view=$project->statusView($_SESSION['uname']);
    foreach($status2view as $row){

        $updateid=$row['update_id'];
        $account_name=$row['account_name'];
        $os_id=$row['os_id'];
        $author=$row['author'];
        $post_date=$row['time'];
        $title= stripslashes($row['title']);
        $data= stripslashes($row['update_body']);

        $statusdeletebutton='';


        $sql1="select * from updates,comment_update 
                where comment_update.os_id like updates.update_id 
                  and comment_update.type like 'b'";

        $sql2="select * from updates 
                 left join comment_update using (os_id) 
               where comment_update.os_id=:statusid limit 1 ";

        $stmth=$conn->prepare($sql2);
       // $stmth->bindparam(":either",$_SESSION['uname']);
        $stmth->bindparam(":statusid",$updateid);
        $stmth->execute();
        $status_reply= $stmth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        foreach ($status_reply as $row1) {

            $status_reply_id=$row1['comment_id'];

            $reply_author=$row1['author'];
            $reply_d=htmlentities($row1['comment_body']);
            $reply_data=  stripslashes($reply_d);
            $reply_osid=$row1['os_id'];
            $reply_date=$row1['time'];
            $reply_delete_button="";
            if ($reply_author==$_SESSION['uname'] ) {
                $reply_delete_button.="<li><span id='$status_reply_id' class='delete_reply_btn glyphicon glyphicon-remove'><a href='#' title='Delete this comment'>Remove X</a></span></li>";
            }
            if ($updateid==$reply_osid) {  
                $status_replies.="<div  class='replyboxes pull-left reply_".$status_reply_id."'>Reply by:-<a href='search_results.php?u=".$reply_author."'>".$reply_author."</a>"
                      . "<span class='pull-right'>".$reply_date 
                       . "<b class='caret'>
                         <small><span class='btn-xs btn-danger dropdown-toggle pull-right' data-toggle='dropdown' aria-expanded='true' ><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span>
                        <ul class='dropdown-menu'>".$reply_delete_button
                      . "<li><a href='#' class='hidden_text_area glyphicon glyphicon-pencil reply_".$status_reply_id."' title='Edit this comment' >Edit</a></li>"
                      . "<li><a href='report.php?u='".$reply_author."'>Report</a><li></ul>"
                      . "</span></span></small></b><br><legend>".  html_entity_decode($reply_data)."</legend><br></div>";
            }  else {
                $status_replies.="";
            }


            //insert_status_ui script to get message.
            if ($author==$_SESSION['uname'] || $account_name==$_SESSION['uname']) {
                $statusdeletebutton='<li>'
                           . '<a href="#" type="'.$updateid.'" class="delete_4_session hidden_text_delete_'.$updateid.' glyphicon glyphicon-trash delete_reply_btn" title="Delete this status and its replies">Remove</a></li>';
             }



             $status_list= $statusui_edit.'<div attr="'.$updateid.'" type="'.$updateid.'" class="statusboxes status_'.$updateid.'  jumbotron">'
                        . '<h3 style="color:black; margin-bottom:5px; margin-top:5px;" class="pull-left">'
                        . '<div id="'.$updateid.'" class="title_s_2copy" value="'.html_entity_decode($title).'">'.html_entity_decode($title).'</div></h3>'
                        . '<span class="pull-right">'
                        . '<div class="dropdown">'
                        . '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"  >'
                        . '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></button>'
                        . '<ul class="dropdown-menu">'
                        . '<li><a href="#" attr="'.$updateid.'" type="'.$updateid.'" class="edit_4_session hidden_text_edit glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" title="Edit this status" >Edit</a></li>'.$statusdeletebutton.'</ul></div></span><br><hr>'
                        . '<legend><span class=" data_s_2copy" type="'.$updateid.'" >'
                        . html_entity_decode($data).'</span><br><br></legend><b style="text-align:right; color:black;"><small>Posted by:-  <a href="search_results.php?u='.$author.'">'.$author.   '</a>   '.$post_date.'</small></b>'
                        . '<br><p>'.$status_replies.'</p><br>';

             $status_list.= '<textarea id="reply_textarea_'.$updateid.'"  class="status_reply_'.$updateid.' input-custom2" placeholder="comment\'s"></textarea>'
                            . '<button id="reply_btn_'.$updateid.'" attr="'.$updateid.'" type="b" class="btn btn-warning pull-right btn-sm reply_btn reply_'.$updateid.'">Reply</button></div>';

         }   
         echo $status_list;
   }
```

here is a screenshot of that schema:
[image]

Comment: Note that `LEFT JOIN x ... WHERE x...` is the same as `INNER JOIN x ON x...`

Comment: i tried that while debugging but not working @Strawberry

Comment: Tried what? I'm just pointing out that the two statements are identical. If one doesn't work, the other won't work either!

Comment: using the on function in the query bro!

Comment: `LEFT JOIN x` = `LEFT JOIN x ON 1=1`, so it always matches, so it won't output `NULL`s, so it's an `INNER JOIN`. Since it doesn't matter whether `INNER JOIN` tests are in some `INNER JOIN`'s `ON` or in a `WHERE`, `LEFT JOIN x ON/WHERE x.c=...` = `INNER JOIN x ON/WHERE x.c=...`. (Per @Strawberry.) But `w LEFT JOIN x USING (c)` = `w LEFT JOIN x ON w.c=x.c`. It can output rows with `x.c`s `NULL`. Then if we add `WHERE x.c=...` the test can't be true & removes them. So it's an `INNER JOIN`. But if you want `LEFT JOIN` then you likely want `w LEFT JOIN x USING (c) WHERE x.c IS NULL OR x.c=...`.

Comment: Please read about [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).